# Dbus.Array (Reading pidgin messages from python)

Tags: python, dbus, pidgin

I am trying to read a message on a pidgin window using python. I have read [Pidgin how to](https://developer.pidgin.im/doxygen/dev2.x.y/html/signal-howto.html) and I using the following code:

```
purple.PurpleGetConversations()
```

and I get the following output:

```
dbus.Array([dbus.Int32(14414)], signature=dbus.Signature('i'))
```

I dont know how to access the elements of this dbus.Array

Best Regards

PD: I am interested in reading the messages, if there is a better way please let me know

Progress update: If anyone else is interested in this, I came up with an alternative solution. Pidgin leaves chat logs in ~/purple, from python you can open this files and use regex to read all msgs.

(If there is a more straigthforward way please tell me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, Here is the resulting code:

```
    convID = purple.PurpleGetConversations()

    msgpos = purple.PurpleConversationGetMessageHistory(convID[0])[0]

    print purple.PurpleConversationMessageGetMessage(msgpos)
```

This will print the last message from an open chat

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PurpleConversationGetChatData` method, it takes conversation id as a parameter (14414 in your case).

I have javascript client generated from introspection xml, it might be helpful addition to a dbus documentation - https://github.com/sidorares/node-pidgin/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Thank you, this sounds perfect. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Thanks to your answer @Andrey I got to [List of pidgin Methods](http://pidgin.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.4.3-4lenny8/conversation_8h_4bf104e6b7080e7af44c10c2cce0aea3.html#4bf104e6b7080e7af44c10c2cce0aea3) and I found what i was looking for. Thank you